# Toggle expand not working in jquery 1.11.0

Tags: jquery, css

I have a piece of code with toggle buttons to expand an area.  It works up to jquery 1.8.3 and starts breaking when I use a newer version of jquery (My target is 1.11.0, to work with Bootstrap 3.)  Does anyone have a suggestion for making this work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#slide1').css("height", "auto");
    var slideHeight = $('#slide1').height();
    $('#slide1').css("height", "95");

    if (slideHeight < 95) {
        $('#toggler-slide1').hide();
    }


    $('#slide2').css("height", "auto");
    var slideHeight = $('#slide2').height();
    $('#slide2').css("height", "95");

    if (slideHeight < 95) {
        $('#toggler-slide2').hide();
    }

    $(".toggler").toggle(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var widgetId = id.substring(id.indexOf('-') + 1, id.length);
        $('#' + widgetId).css("height", "auto");
        var height = $('#' + widgetId).height();
        $('#' + widgetId).css("height", "95");
        $('#' + widgetId).animate({
            height: height
        }, 200, 'linear');
        $(this).toggleClass('sliderExpanded');
    }, function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var widgetId = id.substring(id.indexOf('-') + 1, id.length);
        $('#' + widgetId).animate({
            height: 95
        }, 200, 'linear');
        $(this).removeClass('sliderExpanded');
    });

});
```

A working version, running on 1.8.3, is below.  Change the version to see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7eKT/1/

Comment: .toggle no longer binds an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ says:

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed.